# Can you Identify our relation?

Tags: logical-deduction, family

> I have only one brother.
>
> My brother's wife name is Clara.
>
> Clara has only one sister. Her name is Sara.
>
> Sara's sister is also sister to me.

How?

Comment: Does 'brother'/'sister' exclude a potential half-brother/sister interpretation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sara's sister is

> a nun. She is genetically no sister for anyone else, still, she is called a sister by them.

Comment: could you please explain how does this affect the relations?

Comment: I think Mike is working off of the wording that "she is also a sister to me", being different from "is my sister". You call nuns sisters. You could also do the same with Mormon female missionaries.

Comment: Well done mike.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible if, for example:

> Your brother and you have a father, Harry and a mother, Louise
>  Harry had a child with Jill called Tara (so Tara is your sister)
>  Jill had a child with Bob called Sara (so Tara is Sara's sister)
>  Bob had a child with Alice called Clara (Sara is Clara's sister)
>  Neither Bob nor Alice had any other daughters (Sara is Clara's *only* sister)
>  Your brother married Clara.

Like so (black lines parentage, blue line marriage):

> [image: relationships]

Comment: Great! Well tried.

Comment: So, are you expecting a solution without "half-sisters" (or even easier, "step-sisters")?

Answer (score 5):

> Incest. Actually, the riddle says you only have one brother, but that doesn't rule out you having a sister, or multiple sisters. So you brother marries your sister Clara, and Clara's sister Sara is also your sister, because incest.

Answer (score 5):

> You are male, and have a brother and two sisters. Your sisters are named Sara and Clara.

Now there are two possibilities. The one involving the least number of people is

> Your brother married your sister Clara.

However the more likely situation is

> Since nowhere it is said that both times Clara is mentioned, the same person is meant, your brother may have married another woman whose name is *also* Clara.

Answer (score 3):

> If you have sisters Clara and Sara, and then your brother's wife name is also Sara it will work. The way you define it it's not clear if Clara from 'Clara has only one sister' is the same Clara as your brother's wife.

Comment: You are not your brother.

Comment: @celtschk Ah! You are right!

Answer (score 2):

I think

> Sara is your wife!

so her sister is your sister, too.

Answer (score 2):

I can think like this.

> There is a chance of having a second wife for the father. Sara may be the child of father and the second wife. Clara may have been there before father married her.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be:

> You are Sara

I have only one brother

My brother's wife name is Clara.

> Your brother is married to Clara

Clara has only one sister. Her name is Sara.

> You are Clara's **sister**-in-law

Sara's sister is also sister to me.

> Your sister is your own sister, of course

Or a slightly different interpretation

> Your brother is your brother-in-law

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is

> Clara is your sister in law. Clara married your brother. Clara has a sister named Sara. Sara has a sister named Clara. Clara is called your sister in law. Little back and forth, but it is pretty clear because of the exclusions.